# Why is this UIButton not rounding Swift?

Tags: swift, uibutton, uibarbuttonitem, uiedgeinsets

I have this UINavigationBarButton I am making with an image inside of it that is originally square. I have used this code on other regular buttons and it has made the images round. However, it is not working for this button and I have no idea why. Also, I do not know how to make it smaller. (but don't mind its placement)

```
func preloadMe() {

    let btn1 = UIButton(type: .custom)
    let completelink = self.me[0].picture_url
    self.loadProfilePhoto(image: btn1, link: completelink)
    btn1.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40)
    btn1.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * btn1.frame.height
    //btn1.setImage(UIImage(named: "profileMenuButton"), for: .normal)
    btn1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(HomeViewController.menuClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
    let item1 = UIBarButtonItem(customView: btn1)
    btn1.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -70, -10, 0)
    self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItems([item1], animated: true)

}

   func loadProfilePhoto(image: UIButton, link: String) {
    image.downloadedFrom2(link: link)
    image.imageView!.clipsToBounds = true
    image.imageView!.layer.cornerRadius = (image.imageView!.frame.height) / 2
    image.imageView!.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    }
```

[image: As you can see in the top left it is still square.]

After a suggestion of adding in `btn1.backgroundColor = .black`
  I am now getting this result. What should I do now?

[image: The new result]

Answer (score 0):

Your button background color is nil. That's why drawing context is not visible. Set your button background color and your problem will be solved.

```
btn1.backgroundColor = .black
```

Comment: Ok, it is somewhat on the right track. I am uploading a photo of what it looks like now, the photo is completely separated from the button and is still square, but the button is round. I will edit the original post with the new photo

Comment: why do you set imageView of the button rather than setImage or setBackgorundImage?